# I am using firebase_admob to implement abmob in my flutter app, but ads are not working in release build apk

Tags: android, flutter, admob

I am using firebase_admob to implement ads in my flutter app. The ads are just work fine in emulator by using test ads and also by using my own banner ads but upon release build of the app, no ads are showing in my app in real device.

Comment: Can you share your code for admob? @Rajneesh

Comment: I have integrated admob in 6-7 apps and all are working fine in iOS and Android both

Comment: ads are actually working in emulator but not in real device with build release apk.

Answer (score 0):

It takes some time for real ads to show on a new app. May take up to several days.